# Correct Structure for Multiple Non-hierarchical Keys in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for some advice on how to model a table in DynamoDB where I need to lookup on several different keys. The object looks like this:

```
{
  memberId: string;
  cognitoUserId: string;
  cognitoTmpPassword: string;
  email: string;
  britecoreGroupId: string;
  policyNumbers: string[];
}
```

We need to be able to perform lookups by memberId, cognitoUserId or email for different use cases. What is the optimal way to structure the table for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think secondary indexes are what I need. All good.